# How can I use Invoke() function in SAP B1 SDK?

Tags: vb.net, sdk, sapb1

I have one problem of function (Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})) which gives error message 'Invoke' is not a member of 'SysForm.SystemForm'. I think it does not work in SAP SDK,

Actually my codes look like this

```
    Private Sub myserialport_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles myserialport.DataReceived
        ReceivedText(myserialport.ReadExisting())
    End Sub 
  Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String)
        If Me.textbox1.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallBack(AddressOf ReceivedText)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else
            Me.texbox1.text &= [text]
        End If
    End Sub
```

The problem is in line of Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})

I will replace texbox1 with SAP field

How can I use Invoke() function in SAP B1 or which function can replace it in SAP B1 SDK?

Please anyone can help me

Comment: If you're testing the `InvokeRequired` property of a `TextBox` then why wouldn't you call the `Invoke` method of that same `TextBox`? Even if it worked, it makes no sense not to use those two members of the same object.

Answer (score 0):

SAP UI controls don't support `Invoke` AFAIK. They are completely separate from any out of the box .Net UI controls.

I don't understand enough about what you're trying to do to suggest an alternative though.

Answer (score 0):

I used a similar code.

Maybe this code can help

```
Type mtype = Caller.GetType();
MethodInfo mMethod = mtype.GetMethod(mthdname);
mMethod.Invoke(Caller, new object[] { kacadet, aragun, ayingunu });

oForm.Close();
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```